# Why my code does not work? Does not return error but does not remove values from D1 column. I need to remove rows based on criterian

Tags: excel, vba

***Why my code does not work?  I need to remove rows based on criteria.
we have error running your example run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error mark this line ***

```
            Case .Cells(i1, 1).Text Like "*бочка*", .Cells(i1, 1).Text Like "*(Б/У)*", .Cells(i, 1).Text, " БУ "
```

Comment: Your second `If` is missing an `End If`.  Put it just before the `Else` statement.

Comment: Also, it is more robust to remove rows working from lastRow to firstRow, else your counter may get confused.

Comment: why values do not remove from column D4 ?

Comment: please give me example of lastRow to FirstRow use with many values to remove

Answer (score 0):

Removing rows requires looping backwards through the range because as rows are removed in a forward looping everything shifts up and thus data gets skipped. Also, executing one remove statement will speed up code execution.

```
Option Explicit

Sub removeData()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") '<- change name as needed

    Dim i1 As Long
    i1 = 1

    With ws.Range("D1").CurrentRegion

        Do While i1 <= .Rows.Count

            Select Case True

                Case .Cells(i1, 1).Value Like "*бочка*", .Cells(i1, 1).Value Like "*(Б/У)*", .Cells(i, 1).Value, " БУ "

                    Dim remove As Range
                    If Not remove Is Nothing Then
                        Set remove = Union(remove, .Cells(i1, 1))
                    Else
                        Set remove = .Cells(i1, 1)
                    End If

            End Select

            i1 = 1

        Loop

    End With

    remove.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: @daveramsey - see my edits and try again, please. yesterday I got very busy

Comment: @daveramsey - it's possible VBA is not liking that character set you are using. Otherwise, the code works for me with character set that my machine can recoginze.

Comment: error variable not define and marked Sub removeData()